# GIT conflict development

Tags: git

I have performed a git pull into my local repository and I received a conflict in the log/development.log file

```
Auto-merging log/development.log
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in log/development.log
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I do not have much experience with GIT and fixing conflicts. Any advice on how to go about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/161813/1615903

Comment: Also, I don't think a log file should be in the repository. See [information about gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add all log files to .gitignore

```
      log/*.*
```

Answer (score 1):

You should to add log folder in .gitignore. it's not best practice to stash log over git.

You can use "git gui" for conflict resolve.

but need to install git-gui.

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-gui
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have made some local modifications that haven't been pushed.

Best way to go is to pull your remote in a different branch if you are having trouble.

Log files are likely to be modified all the time (that's what they're here for ^^). 
Take it out of the repo and you should be fine.

Edit : Or as suggested, use git-mergetool. It gives you more precise control on how the files will be merged.

Answer (score 0):

Fix conflict by using "git mergetool" and then continue.

On Linux a very good tool is meld:

git config --global merge.tool meld